# Allow Anonymous Attribute in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

Hello I am developing an Intranet web site using `MVC 4` and `Forms Authentication`. Web site project properties Anonymous Authentication is `"Disabled"`

And in `web.config` file

```
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
```

After that I add and attribute `[Authorize]` to my `Controller` and `[AllowAnonymous]` to my Login `Action`. But when I open Login Action it shows `401.2 Unauthorize error`.

Comment: Does <deny users="?"/> mean to deny anonymous users to your resource?  I believe the default is usually <allow users="*" /> which means to accept authenticated users.  Not sure if this is your issue though.

Comment: I removed authorization from web.config and used [Authorize] for all Controllers and this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed authorization from web.config and used [Authorize] for all Controllers and this solved my problem.